# PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:

Tags: node.js, next.js, rest, prisma

I am trying to create an API using Next.js & Prisma. I have two model user & profile.
I want to create user & also profile field from req.body using postman.

```
datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  email   String @unique
  password String
  profile Profile?
}

model Profile {
  id     Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  bio    String?
  user   User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int   @unique
}

here my create function:

 //Create User
   let { name, email, password,  } = req.body;
    const createUser = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        password: user_password,
        profile: {
          create: { bio: 'Bsc' }
          },  
      }
    });
    res.status(201).json({ error: false, msg: "User Create Successfuly" });
```

After URL hit I got an error.
PrismaClientValidationError: Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation
Unknown arg `profile` in data.profile for type UserCreateInput. Did you mean `email`?
Available args:type UserCreateInput

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6):

I have resolved this issue with the command

```bash
npx prisma generate
```

Comment: man this helped me a lot I was just struggling fooling around very much thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, stop the server from running first and try to :
`npx yarn-upgrade-all`

`yarn add @prisma/client`

`npx prisma migrate reset`

Comment: This will drop your entire database and tables... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to adjust and clarify your code

```
     //Create User
//because you had already created  and get variables 
 from the body here
   let { name, email, password,  } = req.body;
    const createUser = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
//no need to reassign them here
        name,
        email,
        password,
//the  profile creation is missing elements here, you just put  the 'bio' where are //the other elements???
        profile: {
          create: { bio: 'Bsc' }
          },  
      }
    });
```

Note: Lines with + are required, lines with ? are optional.
In your schema, what kind of relation is this? The User belongs to Profile or the Profile belongs to the user?

```
    model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
  email   String @unique
  password String
  profile Profile  ?//<= Adjust  the Foreign key. Do you mean an array of 
             //profile or  a unique profile?
}

model Profile {
  id     Int     @default(autoincrement()) @id
  bio    String?
  userId Int   @unique// userId goes before  the relation declaration
  user   User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  
}
```